# How to convert values of one column into column headers and other column values into rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how my df looks like.

```
    A      B     C      D      E      F
    xyz   abc    aa    100    qq     brc,pqr,lmn
    xyz   abc    bb    150    qq     lmn,brc,ppq
    xyz   abc    cc    80     qq     lmn,pqr
    abc   pqr    cc    99     qq     pqr,brc,lmn
    abc   pqr    aa    180    qq     brc,lmn,pqr
    abc   pqr    bb    200    qq     lmn,pqr,brc
```

this is what i want. how can i achieve the same?

```
A      B     aa     bb    cc      E      F
xyz   abc    100   150    80      qq     brc,pqr,lmn,ppq
abc   pqr    180   200    99      qq     brc,lmn,pqr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for another DataFrame created by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(set(z for y in x for z in y.split(',')))
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'E':'first', 'F': f})

df = df.pivot_table(index=['A','B'],
                    columns='C',
                    values='D',
                    aggfunc='mean').join(df1).reset_index()
print (df)
     A    B   aa   bb  cc   E                F
0  abc  pqr  180  200  99  qq      lmn,brc,pqr
1  xyz  abc  100  150  80  qq  lmn,ppq,brc,pqr
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but I am getting the error as 'No numeric types to aggregate' as the data type is string for values. what can i do about it?

Comment: @Prachi - You can use `df.D = df.D.astype('int')` or some another solumn from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas) like `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: ok, i did that. but my output doesnt look like how i want it. i actually got the column 'cc' twice and the values seperated too. i tried df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1).first() but it didnt work too.

Comment: @Prachi - There are not some space like columns are `'cc'` and `' cc'` ? What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` after my solution?

Comment: After your solution these are the columns i get `['A', 'B', ' cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'E', 'F']`

Comment: @Prachi - Thank you, so problem is `cc` has space, so need before my solution `df.C = df.C.str.strip()` for convert `' cc'` to `'cc'`